# c++ Pass variable value from one code block to another

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, scope

Checkbox doesn't change the value of "**use_Xml**" variable that is being written to a file.
This is a matter of scope I think, but I don't know how to do it right. I'm a beginner.
This has been probably answered a lot of times already but I just don't know how to ask the question right and find the answer. I will agree to a redirect to a relevant question.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
...
string use_Xml = "1";
...

LRESULT CALLBACK WinProc(HWND hWnd,UINT message,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI WinMain(...) {...}

    LRESULT CALLBACK WinProc(HWND hWnd,UINT msg,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam)
    {

        switch(msg)
        {

        case WM_COMMAND:

        switch(LOWORD(wParam))
        {

            case IDC_MAIN_CHKBX_X:
            {

                UINT checkedX = IsDlgButtonChecked(hWnd, IDC_MAIN_CHKBX_X);

                switch (checkedX)
                {

                case BST_CHECKED:
                    {
                    CheckDlgButton(hWnd, IDC_MAIN_CHKBX_X, BST_UNCHECKED);
                    SetWindowText(hWnd, TEXT("no"));
                    use_Xml = "0";
                    }
                    break;

                case BST_UNCHECKED:
                    {
                    CheckDlgButton(hWnd, IDC_MAIN_CHKBX_X, BST_CHECKED);
                    SetWindowText(hWnd, TEXT("yes"));
                    use_Xml = "1";
                    }
                    break;
                }

            }
            break;

            case IDC_MAIN_BUTTON_S:
            {
                ofstream myfile ("foo.ini");
                myfile << use_Xml << "\n";
                myfile.close();
            }
            break;
        }
        break;

        }

        return DefWindowProc(hWnd,msg,wParam,lParam);
    }
```

Comment: Where and how is `use_Xml` defined?

Comment: Also having `use_Xml` as a `string` seems to be a questionable approach. Why not have a `bool` represent a boolean value?

Comment: Is `use_Xml` `string` or `bool` ?

Comment: Is `myfile.is_open()` definitely `true` prior to the write to file? In the posted code, if any file operation fails it fails silently.

Comment: String is easier for me to write to a file, at the moment, I guess. But that wouldn't solve the issue, be it a string or a bool... Right?

Comment: @hmjd it writes to a file ok, several values in fact... But the **old** value of this particular variable...

Answer (score 1):

The return value of [`IsDlgButtonChecked()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761879%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a `UINT` and not a `BOOL`. From the linked reference page:

```
Return code       Description

BST_CHECKED       The button is checked.

BST_INDETERMINATE The button is in an indeterminate state (applies only 
                  if the button has the BS_3STATE or BS_AUTO3STATE style).

BST_UNCHECKED     The button is not checked.
```

It may be that all of these values are non-zero resulting in the same execution path being taken irrespective of the state of the check box in the dialog.
Correct the code and add diagnostic logging to the `if/else` that uses the return value to confirm the code execution paths.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand what you mean. I will try it now. TY. I'll have to google diagnostic logging though.

Comment: @JohnDoh, _diagnostic logging_: just write to a file or `std::cout`.

Comment: I added SetWindowText to if statement and it does work as expected - checkbox state corresponds to text in the title of an app. I'm not sure how to adept my code further. If I define the checking Func as UINT type, then against what values do I check - BST_CHECKED/BST_UNCHECKED?

Comment: I made the requested corrections. Execution paths confirmed. That didn't change anything though. What about the scope issue? I think the problem is that those variables (use_Xml), each being in it's own code block, are considered as two separate and independent, both in their own scope...

Comment: @JohnDoh, no they are the same variable as `use_Xml` is global. Print the address of `use_Xml` somewhere to satisfy yourself this is the true: `std::cout << &use_Xml << "\n";`.